# Can't ssh even with public key added to authorized_keys

Tags: networking, 16.04, ssh

I have a Digital Ocean droplet I'm trying to give myself ssh access to. I'm not sure what was done to it previously. I've tried added my public key through the Digital Ocean UI. That didn't work, I kept getting `permission denied (publickey)`.

I accessed the server through the Digital ocean console and manually added my public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I then tried to ssh using `ssh root@x.x.x.x`. That didn't work (permission denied).

So I tried adding a new user, created the `/home/me/.ssh` directory with permissions `700` on the `.ssh` directory itself, and `600` on the `authorized_keys` file. Then I tried `ssh me@x.x.x.x`. That didn't work either.

Restarting the ssh daemon doesn't change anything either.

What am I missing?

Edit:

Here is verbose ssh output.

https://gist.github.com/jaesung2061/a37cfd68308414cede8abf7f0137daa9

Edit 2:

`LogLevel DEBUG3` output:

[image]

Comment: Post the verbose log from the connection, your content of sshd_config  and possible errors related to ssh in the server log.

Comment: @Jakuje I've added the output... I didn't notice your comment before.

Comment: The key is rejected. Check the server log for possible issues (possibly with `LogLevel DEBUG3` in `sshd_config`). I suspect these are permission issues, but there might be several reasons for this.

Comment: It says `[date omitted] www sssh[15029]: Connection closed by x.x.x.x port 55519 [preauth]`

Comment: What are the permissions of the authorized_keys file? `ls -ld ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`? For the verbose log from server modify the file mentioned above, restart ssh service, connect again and post the log (should be also in `auth.log`.

Comment: Here are the permissions: http://imgur.com/a/soyB5. Here is the latest log entry after ssh restart and login attempt: http://imgur.com/a/97jiy.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the file permissions on the server (for `root` user you are connecting to). There are no more logs? This is the same as you already posted and is not helpful.

Comment: Yes that was from the server. `jeff` is a user on the server with root permissions.

Comment: ok, I got confused because you are trying to do and describe two things at once. If there is nothing in the auth.log, it should be certainly in journal (`journalctl -b`).

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/12zdS is `journalctl -b` output. The "whited" area is one of the domain names hosted on the server..

Comment: Please, set `LogLevel DEBUG3` in the start of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, restart ssh service `systemctl restart ssh` and the output of journalct post as a text, not image. There should be a lot of more logs.

Comment: @Jakuje `LogLevel DEBUG3` output http://imgur.com/a/OOTfb.

Comment: @Jeff please append last lines of your ssh log file (`/var/log/auth.log`) that related to this failed login into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling `openssh-server` which fixed the issue. The solutions given are all great, but they didn't work for me. I have no idea what was causing the issue but I think the previous developer may have messed with the configuration and messed things up pretty bad.

I doubt there will be anyone with such a specific issue as mine. However, if you have a Digital Ocean droplet, you cannot get SSH access, and none of the given solutions work, reinstall the SSH server by running these commands through the Digital Ocean console. **Beware this is a destructive process and will erase old configuration files in `/etc/ssh/`** (not your `.ssh` directory).

```
apt-get purge openssh-server
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
apt-get install openssh-server
```

Assuming your ssh client/keys are in order, you should be able to SSH into your server.

Answer (score 34):

## Client Configuration

### Set up `~/.ssh/config`

Setting up host entries for `ssh` is really easy and will save you a lot of trouble.  Here is an example:

```
Host digitaloceanbox
Hostname 111.111.111.111
User root
PubKeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/digitalocean-rsa
ForwardX11 yes


Host github github.com
Hostname github.com
User git
PubKeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /home/user/.ssh/github-rsa
ForwardX11 no
```

In this example, we setup `digitaloceanbox` and `github` and `github.com` so that we can do the following commands:

1. `ssh github`
2. `ssh digitaloceanbox`

If we want to login as a different user than the one specified in the config file, we just put `user@` at the begining:

- `ssh user@digitaloceanbox`

### Generating `ssh` keys

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C user@homemachine
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa):  /home/user/.ssh/digitalocean-rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/digitalocean-rsa
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/digitalocean-rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:p9PYE/tveF2n//bLbp3ogYDtMtYEC5ziQiPxeob6fbo user@homemachine
```

Note that I've specified the full path of the private key I want to generate when prompted by `ssh-keygen`.  I've also defined the comment (`-C`) which allows me to easily identify keys on remote machines.

This will create two files:

1. `.ssh/digitalocean-rsa`

   - **PRIVATE** key.  **Never share this**.
2. `.ssh/digitalocean-rsa.pub`

   - Public key.  This is what you store on the server to authenticate.

When you provide your `ssh` key, be sure it's the `.pub` version!!  When you add to your `~/.ssh/config`, be sure to add the correct private key that matches the public key you added to the system.

---

## Server Configuration

Most installations will come with Public Key Authentication enabled.  If you start doing things all willy nilly, you might run into a few problems, however.  At where the OP is in their problem, I recommend that the OP deletes the `/root/.ssh/` directory to start over.

It is not recommended that you use `ssh` to access the root user on the remote system.  It is recommended that you `ssh` into another user, and then escalate to root using your password (`sudo su -`).

### Add keys to host using `ssh-copy-id`

Regardless of whether you decide to create another user and use `ssh` as that user, or the root user, the following is the recommended way of placing `ssh` keys on a server:

1. `ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/digitalocean-rsa.pub user@digitaloceanbox`

This allows `sshd` to create the directory and files needed with the permissions needed.  This means there is zero chance for you to mess up permissions or needing to remember the details.  Just use the tool to upload the keys.

### Disable Password Authentication

That being said, once you have key'd yourself and verified that you are able to connect using the keys, it is recommended that you disable Password Authentication in `sshd` and restart the service:

1. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. `PasswordAuthentication no`
3. `sudo systemctl restart sshd`

### What about new users?

If you disable Password Authentication, how can you key new users?  One way is to add template files to the `/etc/skel` directory.  Once you've key'd one user, do the following:

1. `sudo cp -r .ssh/ /etc/skel/`
2. `ls /etc/skel/.ssh`
3. Edit any files found in `/etc/skel/.ssh/` so that they are blank, unless you want to automatically key yourself for every newly created user.

When you create new users with `sudo useradd -m newuser`, that user will have the `.ssh/authorized_keys`, which you can edit and will have the proper permissions.

### Debugging

You can watch the `sshd` log file to see why connections fail or get refused:

1. `sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

While you're running this command, use another terminal to attempt a login.  Many times the messages provided are good enough to help pinpoint the problem, or find a solution online.

Comment: The debugging step worked for me. The root directory had the wrong permissions (needed to be 700)

Comment: Debugging my setup showed that `authorized_keys` had the wrong file mode (the correct mode is 600).

Answer (score 28):

Ssh is quite picky about ownership, file and directory permissions with ssh keys.

~/.ssh/ should be owned by the owner and have 700 permissions.
~/.ssh/authorized_keys should be owned by the owner and have 600 permissions.

So, for root :

```
sudo chown root:root -R /root/.ssh/
sudo chmod 700 /root/.ssh/
sudo chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

For user me :

```
sudo chown me:me -R /home/me/
sudo chmod 700 /home/me/.ssh/
sudo chmod 600 /home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And then try again.

Of course you should also check in /etc/ssh/sshd_config whether root is allowed to log in at all, or just with ssh keys.

If you have :

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

then you can set :

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

And then restart sshd :

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

and try again.

Note that with ssh, the sshd daemon can be restarted even when using an ssh session for this.Openssh is designed to deal with that.

Looking at your uploaded log file snippets, it seems that you are using MacOSX ? Could you create a new ssh key there ?

Furthermore, I found out in the past that when I have more than one private ssh key on my local computer for my user, that this sometimes makes it impossible to log in remotely with ssh. It helped a great lot to make entries on the local computer in the file ~/.ssh/config, to solve this. For example :

```
Host my-vps
  HostName my-vps-ip-address-here
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-my-private-key-location
  User my-username-here
```

After that try on the command line on your local computer :

```
ssh -v my-vps
```

When using ssh keys, as well as no ssh keys for some other logins, you can, besides entries with ssh keys, also define a ssh login without ssh key usage in the ~/ssh/config file, for example :

```
Host pi
  Hostname 192.168.1.111
  Port 22
  User pi
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  PreferredAuthentications password
```

This works fine for me.
It is also possible to define which key to use on the command line :

```
ssh -v root@10.111.111.254 -i .ssh/id_rsa
```

This might make debugging easier, and on the command line this should always work on the local computer.

Comment: In addition to this solution, I had to change the permissions for my home folder too, to get the SSH working: `sudo chmod 700 /home/me/`

Comment: You're a lifesaver, @albert-j!  The `IdentityFile` line got me out of an hour-long rut.

Comment: The permissions thing gets me every time.  Thanks!

Comment: As another answer indicates, you can `sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log` and it will tell you if the home folder permissions are the issue.  I found that 755 is okay, but it does not allow 'w' permissions for group or for other because that would allow other users to change ~/.ssh!!

Comment: SSH is indeed very picky about permissions! I have lost so many hours on these kinds of problems...

Answer (score 5):

Double check the ssh daemon configuration (should be in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and check for:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also check the configuration file to see if *AllowUsers* or *AllowGroups* has been set, as they act as white lists for user and groups respectively.

Also, I noticed you're trying to add a key to the root user. By default root login should be disabled, but you can also change this via the *PermitRootLogin* field.

Comment: None of these are working :/ I still get `Permission denied (publickey)`

Answer (score 4):

According to the logs you have linked, I think you have problems in the client side not finding the *private key* file.

- First check the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` exists on your local machine, and is the correct one _(if you have more).
- Check `.ssh` folder permissions *(should be `drwx------`, if not run `sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh`)* and its contents *(should be `-rw-------`, if not run `sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*`)*. Apply the same permissions for the remote machine too.

Additionally, you can try to force using your desired *private key*, giving it directly to `ssh` with the `-i` parameter.

- You can run something like the followings:

  `ssh -i /path/to/your/private-key root@X.X.X.X`

  or

  `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myRemoteUser@X.X.X.X`

You can get more info on ssh manpage *(run `man ssh` on your terminal)*.

Also keep in mind if you want to login as `root` user, your root account has to be enabled prior to login, creating a passwd for it with `sudo passwd root` or your server administration tool *(Ubutntu has root account disabled by default)*. You can get more info at [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#root_account).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This issue popped up for me using the Debian image on Digital Ocean. Somehow during the brief set up process, probably when I set the root password, the owner for `/root` was changed to the user `debian`. I saw the following in `/var/log/auth.log`:

`Jul 26 20:58:17 docker sshd[12576]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /root`

Simply executing `chown root:root -R /root` solved the issue.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just had a very similar problem. This worked for me - Add this line to */etc/ssh/sshd_config*

```
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then restart ssh in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you've copied your public key from your local machine to your remote server via `scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub myUser@129.124.135.100:~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (replace `myUser` and `29.124.135.100` with your user and server IP respectively) and you're sure that you got all the permissions right as suggested by other answers in this post.

Edit `sshd_config` file via `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

enable public key authentication:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

and disable password authentication:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Save by pressing `escape` key then typing `:wq` to write the buffer and quit vim.

Restart ssh via `sudo systemctl restart ssh` or `sudo systemctl restart sshd` command depending on your system (run both if you're not sure).

Logout and try to ssh into your remote server from your client local machine again.

Now it should only attempt to log you in via your private SSH key.

`ssh myUser@129.124.135.100` or `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myUser@129.124.135.100`

If you were immediately logged in without entering any passphrase, then it's very likely that you didn't set a passphrase to your private key to begin with!