# ftp 18.10 no route to host exception

Tags: 18.10, ftp

Trying to connect to a server ftp.sel2in.com but get

> ftp
> ftp> open ftp.sel2in.com
>
> ftp: connect: No route to host
>
> ftp>

Same with filezilla client

I'm able to ping and ssh into the server.
After I ssh i can do an ftp from that shell. Not an admin of that server, own a folder on there with php and mysql (x10hosting.com if that helps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `sftp`?  Also, if you have `ssh` access, you can use `scp`, which allows you to upload and download files.  As `ftp` is not encrypted, it is highly recommended you find an alternative solution.

```bsh
$ scp path/to/local/file me@domain.tld:/path/to/remote/file  # Download file
$ scp path/to/local/file me@domain.tld:path/in/home/directory  # Download file in home directory
$ scp me@domain.tld:/path/to/remote/file path/to/local/file  # Upload file
```

Whether you chose `sftp` or `scp` is up to you, but it is highly recommended to use over `ftp`, as `ftp` doesn't support encryption.

`rsync` allows for more complicated syncing procedures, and can also utilize `ssh`/`scp`.

You can [set up your `.ssh/config`](https://askubuntu.com/a/311894/13247) to make this easier and look into [setting up ssh keys](https://askubuntu.com/a/875058/13247) as well.

---

Many servers nowadays do not support `ftp`.  Are you 100% sure that this server does?  The ports are all filtered:

```bsh
$ nmap -p 22,21 x10hosting.com
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at sometime
Nmap scan report for x10hosting.com (104.24.22.72)
Host is up (0.013s latency).
Other addresses for x10hosting.com (not scanned): 104.24.23.72

PORT   STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp filtered ftp
22/tcp filtered ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 12.73 seconds
```

Similar to [debugging `ssh`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871751/cant-ssh-even-with-public-key-added-to-authorized-keys/875058#875058), have you checked the server's `ftp` log to see if there are any details there?