# sshfs folder empty after reboot

Tags: server, mount, sshfs, 22.10

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 "Kinetic Kudu" and I am trying to mount a folder via sshfs following instruction I got online:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions server@address:~/ /home/user/Documents/folder
```

And then with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` I add the line:

```
server@address:~/ /home/user/Documents/folder fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,reconnect,identityfile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions 0 0
```

I'm not sure if "`user`" in `identityfile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa` is user of the local machine or the user of the server?

Everything connects well initially, but then after reboot the folder is empty.

Any idea how to solve this?

PS: I'm a newby using `sshfs` and I got the instructions via tutorial [www.digitalocean.com](http://www.digitalocean.com) *How To Use SSHFS to Mount Remote File Systems Over SSH*.

Comment: I would think user is the user trying to access the resource.

Answer (score 0):

You say `server@address`, but really it would be more clear to say `user@server` or `user@address`.  When using `ssh` and the like, the part before the `@` is the user which you're authenticating.

For example, you could set up the following host entry in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host servername
Hostname 192.168.1.102
User banana
```

By default, if you `ssh servername`, you will connect as your current local username.  With this `ssh` configuration present, if you `ssh servername`, you will connect to 192.168.1.102 as `banana`, but even with this setup, if you were to `ssh apple@servername`, you'd connect as `apple` instead.

Your problems are compounded by the fact that mounts in `fstab` are run by the root user on the local system.  This means all the setup in the world as your normal user will not be helpful.  For example, when you `ssh servername` the first time, you accept the public key of the remote server.  This only happens as that user, and if you `sudo su -` to `root`, and run `ssh servername` as root, you will get the same prompt.  This is another common problem when setting up `sshfs` in `fstab` for the first time.

---

The identifier in the public key has no bearing on authentication.  It is simply text to help you identify the specific key on the remote server in case your key is compromised.  When you generate a key, you should make this identifier something related to the machine using the key.  This way, if the machine is compromised, you can remove this specific key from all of your servers without removing other/all keys, helping you maintain and not lose all access.

More details: [SSH Client Configuration](https://askubuntu.com/a/875058/13247)

---

After you reboot, if you run `mount`, you should see all your mounted drives.  My guess is that you will not see this, since the directory is empty.  Just want to mention this, vs successfully mounting an empty directory.

It is possible your drive is not mounting because you have `noauto` in your `fstab` configuration, and the `x-systemd.automount` isn't working properly.

Be sure to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` after making changes to `fstab`.

You can try `mount /home/user/Documents/folder` and see if you get a **specific error**.

If you get no error, it mounts, and you see the files, then this is very likely the case.

Also, you have `allow_other`, but you don't have `user` option.

The drive could be mounted, but you have no `rx` permission to list the files.  This is where `user`, `uid` and `gid` come into play.

```
user@server /mnt/sshfsshare           fuse.sshfs user,_netdev,noauto,defaults,rw,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=2s,Compression=no,cache=yes,kernel_cache,reconnect,uid=1000,gid=1000,idmap=user,allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa  0    2
```

---

You are setting `identityfile`, which I always type as `IdentityFile`, but I don't think the case matters.  This means that even if root runs the mount, it knows to access your key.  You are even correct to use `/home/user` and **not** `~/` in the IdentityFile path.

The only way this could be a problem is if your key file is encrypted/password protected.  In that case, the mount would fail because you haven't entered the password.